# Deploying Contracts Deterministically using Brownie Console

Tags: python, brownie

I am trying to deploy contracts determinsitically using 'salt' via brownie. I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
>>> helloContract = Hello.deploy({'from':accounts[0],'salt':123456})
```

More details:

For example, I am able to deploy my "Hello" Contract deterministically using a factory contract and a salt as below.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Hello {
    string public hello = "Hello";
    }


contract HelloFactory {
    function createHelloWithSalt ( uint _salt ) public returns (address) {    
            Hello helloContract = new Hello {salt: bytes32(_salt)} ();
            return address(helloContract);
            }
    }
```

Using the above Factory, I can create Hello contracts determinsitically through the below code in brownie console.

```
>>> HF = HelloFactory.deploy({'from':accounts[0]})
>>> hello = HF.createHelloWithSalt(123456,{'from':accounts[0]})
>>> # this works
```

Is there any way for me to replicate directly in brownie CLI the same using something like

```
>>> Hello.deploy({'from':accounts[0],'salt':123456)
>>> # doesn't work
```

Comment: It doesn't seem possible. To use the salt parameter you need to deploy the contract with CREATE2 opcode.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible to do. CREATE2 is the opcode which needs to be used in order to use the `{salt}` feature. When you deploy a contract from an EOA (i.e. without a factory), you aren't using this opcode, so you can't do the deployment with a salt.